# Extract and embed data bits into image using matlab

Tags: matlab

I got a question want to raise up here. My problem is I want to embed the 2 LSB from each of the character into 2 * 2 matrix and continuous embed until the data is successfully being embed all. But now I cant make it. Your help is really appreciated. Here is my part of the code.

```
fid = fopen('test.txt'); %open the text file
readText = fread(fid);
fclose(fid); %close the file function
char_in_bit = uint8(readText);
ascii_binary = dec2bin(char_in_bit,7);
size_char = size(char_in_bit); %determine the length of the text file
display(char_in_bit);
display(size_char);

display(BlockRONI);
display(ascii_binary);

for a=1 : size(ascii_binary,1)
    for b=1:6
        if blocksize==2
        n=1;
        for r=1:2
            for c=1:2
                block(r,c)=bitset(block(r,c),1,char_in_bit(n));
                n=n+1;
                block(r,c)=bitset(block(r,c),2,char_in_bit(n));
                %display(block(r,c));
            end
        end
        end
    end
    block(r,c) = bitset(block(r,c), 7, char_in_bit(n));
end

watermarked_image(y2:y2+blocksize-1, x2:x2+blocksize-1)=block;
watermarked_image_int=uint8(watermarked_image);
imwrite(watermarked_image_int,'watermarked.jpg');
```

Comment: Can you reduce your question to contain only the parts relevant to your question? A concise example of an input and the desired output would be appreciated.

Comment: thanks. my question is i want embed the data from text file into the image but it cant function. The below data is my input
1010111
1101001
1101100
1101100
1101001
1100001
1101101

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Do you get an error message or is the result just different than you expected?

Comment: now the embedding can already. Just the output after i extract is totally different to my input. I suspect that the for loop before the bitset got problem, but still cant detect what's the problem on the coding. Hope you all can give me a guides. Thanks